# Cut and sort delimited dates from stdout via pipe

Tags: bash, shell, awk, cut

I am trying to split some strings from stdout to get the dates from it, but I have two cases

```
full.20201004T033103Z.vol93.difftar.gz
full.20201007T033103Z.vol94.difftar.gz
```

Which should produce: 20201007T033103Z which is the nearest date to now (newest)

Or:

```
inc.20200830T033103Z.to.20200906T033103Z.vol1.difftar.gz
inc.20200929T033103Z.to.20200908T033103Z.vol10.difftar.gz
```

Should get the second date (after .to.) not the first one, and print only the newest date: 20200908T033103Z

**What I tried:**

```
cat dates_file | awk -F '.to.' 'NF > 1 {print $2}' | cut -d\. -f1 | sort -r -t- -k3.1,3.4 -k2,2 | head -1
```

This only works for the second case and not covering the first, also I am not sure about the date sorting logic.

Here is a sample data

```
full.20201004T033103Z.vol93.difftar.gz
full.20201004T033103Z.vol94.difftar.gz
full.20201004T033103Z.vol95.difftar.gz
full.20201004T033103Z.vol96.difftar.gz
full.20201004T033103Z.vol97.difftar.gz
full.20201004T033103Z.vol98.difftar.gz
full.20201004T033103Z.vol99.difftar.gz
inc.20200830T033103Z.to.20200906T033103Z.manifest
inc.20200830T033103Z.to.20200906T033103Z.vol1.difftar.gz
inc.20200830T033103Z.to.20200906T033103Z.vol10.difftar.gz
inc.20200830T033103Z.to.20200906T033103Z.vol11.difftar.gz
inc.20200830T033103Z.to.20200906T033103Z.vol12.difftar.gz
inc.20200830T033103Z.to.20200906T033103Z.vol13.difftar.gz
inc.20200830T033103Z.to.20200906T033103Z.vol14.difftar.gz
inc.20200830T033103Z.to.20200906T033103Z.vol15.difftar.gz
inc.20200830T033103Z.to.20200906T033103Z.vol16.difftar.gz
inc.20200830T033103Z.to.20200906T033103Z.vol17.difftar.gz
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get most recent data from your sample data you can use this `awk`:

```
awk '{
   sub(/^(.*\.to|[^.]+)\./, "")
   gsub(/\..+$|[TZ]/, "")
}
$0 > max {
   max = $0
}
END {
   print max
}' file
```

```
20201004033103
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava for this

It's exactly what I want but it has a small issue that it's working always on the first dates in the given input (20200830T033103Z) in inc.20200830T033103Z.to.20200906T033103Z.vol17.difftar.gz

While it should work on the second date (20200906T033103Z) if it exist and if there is no second date in line, it works on first date.

Comment: I tweaked it to be like:

```awk -F. '{ if ( $4 ~ /[0-9]/ ) {gsub(/[TZ]/, "", $4) (a = $4)} else { gsub(/[TZ]/, "", $2) (a = $2) }  } a > max{max = a} END{print max}'```

This is working perfectly fine now

Thanks a lot @anubhava

Comment: @Wazery: Please check answer for a shorter awk to achieve this.